# Set transparency of background cover using css

Tags: html, css

Below is code for setting background cover, i want to set transparency of background cover, so that i can display some text over it. I got the solution as below, but its not working for me. I am not getting where am missing it.

```
 style="background: url(images/football_ground.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;-webkit-         
     background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;-moz-opacity:.30; 
filter:alpha(opacity=30); 
-khtml-opacity: 0.3;  ">
```

Comment: what browser are you checking ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, CSS does not allow for a change in the alpha value of a background image. There are a couple different options if you wish to work around this:

1. Simply save your background image as a transparent png of the appropriate opacity.
2. Make the background image it's own absolutely positioned element within the relatively positioned parent container.

.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="foreground">some text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The CSS opacity property sets the opacity of the *whole* element, not just the background. So your code is actually setting the opacity to 0.30 for **both** background *and* text content.

You may need to use 2 elements to achieve what you want.

Comment: U mean different elements for background cover and text??

Comment: Yes. Look at Kyle's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity affects both the element and its descendants.

You don't need to split it into two elements, just use RGB instead to achieve transparency.
The fourth argument, alpha, sets the transparency for the element:

`background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);`

Answer (score 0):

Reaching this now and our requirement was such that the image needed a darker cover, so that the white text placed on top of the image, could be more visible - in case of a whiter background image.

I always used elements to achieve this, but another solution might be to just add this to your parent element's css (or wherever you need it):

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url("./your_image_url");
```

There might even be a shorter way, but I've been using the above at some places.